# Enqueue WP Script that contained PHP variables

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to find out if you can enqueue a script in Wordpress that has php variables within it. If this is possible how would it be done?

I have tried this, however I get errors.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/masonry.php',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your php file called masonry.php

`<?php 
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
$php = 'Hello World';
echo "alert('$php');";`

And then link/enqueue your php as if it was a javascript file:

`wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-script',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/masonry.php',
    array( 'jquery' )
);`

2. You can use `wp_add_inline_script` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) to print the inline code.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.

1. If you want to include a PHP file, use [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) in your PHP file.
2. If you want to include JavaScript file, use [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). Your code should be something like:

   ```
   wp_enqueue_script(
       'custom-script',
       get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/masonry.js',
       array( 'jquery' )
   );
   ```

   Moreover, if you want to use PHP variables inside a JS file, use [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

   After enqueue, use the following line:

   ```
   $name = "my_name";
   $params = array('name' => $name);
   wp_localize_script( 'custom-script', 'OBJECT', $params );
   ```

   Inside your masonry.js, use `OBJECT.name` to get the value.

Comment: Best answer is heren. For sur, better use wp_localize_script !